# How to use variables for width and precision in str.format()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string-formatting

How can I use a variable in the str.format() specification for width and precision?

(I'm in Python 3.)

This works fine:

```
print('    {:<127.127}  {:<}'.format(value[1], value[0]))
```

But this gives an error:

```
SHOWLEN = 127
print('    {:<SHOWLEN.SHOWLEN}  {:<}'.format(value[1], value[0]))
```

Specifically, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Dave\Desktop\index\treeIndex.py", line 101, in <module>
    treeIndex(sys.argv[1])

  File "C:\Users\Dave\Desktop\index\treeIndex.py", line 96, in treeIndex
    print('    {:<SHOWLEN.SHOWLEN}  {:<}'.format(value[1], value[0]))

ValueError: Invalid format specifier
```

How can I use a variable for the precision and width?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Encase `SHOWLEN` in brackets

```
"{varname:<{SHOWLEN}.{SHOWLEN}f}".format(varname=34.54, SHOWLEN=8)
```

This is evident from the following quote from the [Format String Syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings) documentation:

> A format_spec field can also include nested replacement fields within
>   it. These nested replacement fields can contain only a field name;
>   conversion flags and format specifications are not allowed. The
>   replacement fields within the format_spec are substituted before the
>   format_spec string is interpreted. This allows the formatting of a
>   value to be dynamically specified.

Comment: Thanks, but why does that matter?

Comment: It's how the spec works. I've updated my answer with a quote and reference.

Comment: This form also applies to f-string formatting.  Example:  width=5; val=1234; s = f'#{val:{width}}#'; print(s) outputs # 1234#

Answer (score 2):

try

```
print(('    {:<' + str(SHOWLEN) + '.' 
    + str(SHOWLEN) +'}  {:<}').format(value[1], value[0]))
```

This builds a format string from the variable value.

Answer (score 2):

If using the f-string format.

If you were using

```
print(f'{token:10}')
```

And you want the 10 to be another variable (for example the max length of all the tokens), you would write

```
print(f'{token:{maxTokenLength}}')
```

In other words, enclose the variable within `{}`